# Can a MySql stored procedure return multiple resultsets each containing different columns?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have made a stored procedure that returns multiple resultsets from multiple tables. Therefore each resultset is made out of different columns. These resultsets are retrieved by an `ProcedureOutputs` object from the `Hibernate` framework. The first resultset is retrieved with no problems, however Hibernate tries to map the resultsets after that using the column set from the first resultset. This results in the error

`2020-04-26 21:28:55.112 ERROR 22164 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'firstColumnFromFirstResultSet' not found.`

`firstColumnFromFirstResultSet` is an example here.

My question is: Is there any way to let Hibernate know that each resultset is unique and that it shouldn't try to map the second resultset based on the columns of the first resultset?

Thank you

Comment: yes it can and the languages like php java c# support multiquery, buthibernate doesn't, i searched again and i couldn't find any functioning mention of it.

Comment: @nbk thank you, now i know that atleast its not a bug

Comment: hm, it is an old flaw, that should have been corrected.

Comment: @nbk I made an issue for this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13983